log4j2 syslog appender not working in springboot
I'm trying to use log4j2 syslog appender to write messages to syslog from my springboot application.
Here is my log4j2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE XML>
<Configuration name="XMLConfig">
<Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n</Property>
</Properties>
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%highlight{%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36}.%M() @%L - %msg%n%throwable}{FATAL=red blink, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=black, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}" />

    </Console >

    <RollingFile name="RollingFile"
                 fileName="/data/storage/log/app.log"
                 filePattern="/data/storage/log/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.Logs.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max ="100">
            <Delete basePath="/data/storage/log/" maxDepth="2">
                <IfFileName glob="*/app*.Logs.gz" />
                <IfLastModified age="P7D" />
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>
    <Syslog name="Syslog" format="RFC5424" host="127.0.0.1" port="514"
            protocol="UDP" appName="myApp" enterpriseNumber="25979" facility="LOCAL0" />
</Appenders>

<Loggers>

    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
    <Logger name="com.manjosh" level ="error" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Logger>
    <Logger name="com.manjosh.cms.vnf.util.SyslogUtil" level ="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Syslog"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>

I have enabled rsyslog on my server as well
[root@cmsnfv-c_7_1_53_0_standby_karthik ~]# sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 514
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:514           0.0.0.0:*                           2785/rsyslogd 

I also see the log4j is initialized correctly
2024-09-25 09:05:54,098 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=33c7353a
2024-09-25 09:05:54,098 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=33c7353a,component=StatusLogger
2024-09-25 09:05:54,098 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=33c7353a,component=ContextSelector
2024-09-25 09:05:54,099 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=33c7353a,component=Loggers,name=
2024-09-25 09:05:54,099 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=33c7353a,component=Loggers,name=com.manjosh.cms.vnf.util.SyslogUtil
2024-09-25 09:05:54,099 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=33c7353a,component=Loggers,name=com.manjosh
2024-09-25 09:05:54,099 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=33c7353a,component=Appenders,name=Console
2024-09-25 09:05:54,099 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=33c7353a,component=Appenders,name=RollingFile
2024-09-25 09:05:54,099 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=33c7353a, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@4524411f] started OK with configuration XmlConfiguration[location=/opt/dist/WebController/conf/log4j2.xml].
2024-09-25 09:05:54,279 main DEBUG AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=CACHED

but still, I don't see any messages written to /var/log/syslog or localO.log or messages
I see the console and file appenders are working fine.
I'm using springboot 1.5.4
and I'm using
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>


Can you try running
sudo service rsyslog status
Make sure there are no errors. If there are any errors, please restart the service.
Hope the rsyslog is not crashing because of any space or memory issue.
Don't forget to check the log file level permission.

In my syslog appender i was missing mdcId="mdc" includeMDC="true"
I changed it as below and its working now
<Syslog name="Syslog" format="RFC5424" host="127.0.0.1" port="514"
            protocol="UDP" appName="myApp" enterpriseNumber="12345" facility="LOCAL0" mdcId="mdc" includeMDC="true"/>

